# Faster? Many small I/Os or one big I/O?

Tags: c, io, filesystems

I have been working on a project for uni lately, where we are requested to implement a file system that operates inside a regular linux file. (the file is an imaginary partition of a disk) (language: C)
In this context, there are blocks of set size inside the file, where there are multiple entities of the same type all in a row, e.g. directory entries.

My question is:
What's faster? Reading the direntries one by one (using read on the file descriptor) and doing some work with each one, or reading the whole block and doing the work with the data that has been saved into the main memory and, after all the work is done, rewrite the block?

Comment: I would suggest to `mmap()` the whole file, use `madvise()` to set the primary access pattern and let the OS do the rest. This is probably better wrt memory usage and caching than anything you would do manually, and it avoids syscall-overhead

Comment: This sounds more like reading the block on its whole and then rewriting it.
Edit: Plus, mapping the whole file is not possible since it grows indefinitely.

Comment: That's not a real problem, you can `mremap()` it after it grows.

Comment: Sounds like an overhead bigger than the syscalls and the small I/Os. Not sure, though.

Comment: Depends on how often you indeed have to remap, but I doubt that.

Comment: it is always faster to do the job in a memory buffer and read/write bigger chunks. Of course, you can end up with inconsistency or a bad state of the file on the disk in case of crushes. BTW, with memmap you can map just a directory region of the file.

Comment: I know that I can do that with mmap, but this requires that a directory's region in the file is contiguous, which is not.

Comment: If you are simulating a partition (or a whole device) in a file, I'd say that your lowest level should be at block level. This is *below* the HAL. You can't read block devices on byte resolution.

Comment: Thought so. My question, however, was purely performance-wise and solely for this project, which does not explicitly consist of "simulating a partition or device".